# Unable to get statistics of some youtube videos using json link

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

Am trying to get the statistics of youtube video using Api but am not able to get for some videos here is the link I used

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=osY4Szdiv5s&key=apikey&part=statistics
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=KdVvPQVbI_E&key=apikey&part=statistics

Am able to get the stattistics for the second video but not for the first video can any one help me out

Comment: Can you add some code on where you try getting the data or are you just trying to access it through the links? It's hard to say anything with not having the apikey. Can you see data on just the other link if you include the apikey?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to share an apikey here but with that key I could see the data from both videos. For the first video there might be no data available yet so that's why it's not displaying the statistics. YouTube takes time to add these statistics. I think that is the case here or have these videos been up a long time? And are both these videos owned by you and public or private?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube API V3 not returning "statistics" part for /videos endpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271758/youtube-api-v3-not-returning-statistics-part-for-videos-endpoint)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an issue with the API at the moment, an issue has been opened at Google's tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37107133