# Youtube API - cannot get video statistics

Tags: video, youtube

For some unknown reason I cannot get statistics for some youtube videos. I do can do this for most of the videos, but cannot do for some of them. Example:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Je8o9jeo7lQ&key={API_KEY}
So, I get the result, but no statistics there, here is an example:

> { "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse", "etag":
>   "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/gRMbxyKF2W40UYIDVx_WD3Po65w\"",
>   "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 1, "resultsPerPage": 1 }, "items": [ {
>   "kind": "youtube#video", "etag":
>   "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/GpQ48Cl4QPN1W-j4TKdAygXgIow\"", "id":
>   "Je8o9jeo7lQ" } ] }

If I change ?id parameter to any other video ID, I get the statistics of the video. For exampel: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=o_t182PbHl4&key={API_KEY}
So, I don't understand what's wrong with that video. And seams like I cannot get statistics for any video of that channel.

Comment: Have the same trouble, didn't find a way to fix it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271758/youtube-api-v3-not-returning-statistics-part-for-videos-endpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube API V3 not returning "statistics" part for /videos endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271758/youtube-api-v3-not-returning-statistics-part-for-videos-endpoint)